# How can I make this p5.js game faster?

Tags: p5.js

So i have been making this ASCII minecraft clone in p5.js for fun but it is extremely slow

Code:

```
let started = false;
let worldSpacing = 10;
let offx = 0;
let offy = 0;
let worldcharacters = [];
let worldfill = [];
let characters = ["o", "o", "o", " ", "o", "o", " ", "o", "T", "o", "T"];
let worldcharsizes = [];
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  for (let i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    worldcharacters.push(characters[round(random(0, 8))]);

    if (worldcharacters[i] == "T") {
      worldfill.push("rgb(69,26,2)");
      worldcharsizes.push(11)
    } else {
      worldfill.push("rgb(0,106,0)");
      worldcharsizes.push(12.5)
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 30);

  function draworld() {
    for (let j = 0; j < (height / worldSpacing) * 2; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < (width / worldSpacing) * 2; i++) {
        fill(worldfill[i * j]);
        textSize(worldcharsizes[i * j]);
        text(
          worldcharacters[i * j],
          i * worldSpacing + offx,
          j * worldSpacing + offy
        );
      }
    }
  }
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    started = true;
  }

  if (started) {
    draworld();
  } else {
    fill("yellow");
    textSize(((width * 15) / height) * 2);
    text("Click To Start!", ((width * 15) / height) * 9, height / 2);
  }

  if (keyIsPressed) {
    if (key == "w") {
      offy += 1.5;
    }
    if (key == "s") {
      offy -= 1.5;
    }
    if (key == "a") {
      offx += 1.5;
    }
    if (key == "d") {
      offx -= 1.5;
    }
  }
}
```

I really don't know how to make this faster, i have tried making it OOP but it just made it slower and making the characters rows of text instead of being individual but this hindered the ability to mine After all it is **MINE**craft

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing and redrawing each frame which can get computationally expensive.

Instead you could "cache" the rendered text into a `p5.Graphics` "layer"/buffer (which has the same drawing functions as your main sketch). If you do this once in `setup()`, then you can simply display the pre-rendered text using `image()` (which convenientally has `x, y` arguments, handy for a faux camera).

Here's tweaked version of your code illustrating the above:

```js
let started = false;
let worldSpacing = 10;
let offx = 0;
let offy = 0;
let worldcharacters = [];
let worldfill = [];
let characters = ["o", "o", "o", " ", "o", "o", " ", "o", "T", "o", "T"];
let worldcharsizes = [];

let worldBuffer;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  for (let i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    worldcharacters.push(characters[round(random(0, 8))]);

    if (worldcharacters[i] == "T") {
      worldfill.push("rgb(69,26,2)");
      worldcharsizes.push(11)
    } else {
      worldfill.push("rgb(0,106,0)");
      worldcharsizes.push(12.5)
    }
  }
  
  worldBuffer = createGraphics(width, height);
  drawWorld(worldBuffer);
}

function drawWorld(buffer) {
    for (let j = 0; j < (height / worldSpacing) * 2; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < (width / worldSpacing) * 2; i++) {
        buffer.fill(worldfill[i * j]);
        buffer.textSize(worldcharsizes[i * j]);
        buffer.text(
          worldcharacters[i * j],
          i * worldSpacing + offx,
          j * worldSpacing + offy
        );
      }
    }
  }

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 30);

  
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    started = true;
  }

  if (started) {
    image(worldBuffer, offx, offy);
  } else {
    fill("yellow");
    textSize(((width * 15) / height) * 2);
    text("Click To Start!", ((width * 15) / height) * 9, height / 2);
  }

  if (keyIsPressed) {
    if (key == "w") {
      offy += 1.5;
    }
    if (key == "s") {
      offy -= 1.5;
    }
    if (key == "a") {
      offx += 1.5;
    }
    if (key == "d") {
      offx -= 1.5;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Although the above is limited for a full fledged game, the principles still apply and hopefully are easy to follow in this simpler example. (e.g. only render the world if something changes instead of all the time (otherwise, simply display the pre-rendered version)).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I never thought of using the p5.graohics function. You are a genius!